# what exactly is "string programming"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, solr

This page promises me I won't have to do it if I use their software:
http://sunspot.github.com/

What is "string programming"?  Programming characterized by copious string manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sunspot" interfaces with "Solr".

"Solr" is an open-source full-text search engine.

So I guess what *they* mean by "string programming" is the ability to programmatically make full-text searches (using their Sunspot library with Ruby-on-Rails to talk to the Solr full-text search engine).

'Hope that helps

PS:

Here's more info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr

Comment: Yes, because without sunspot (or something like it), you would have to compose your queries by hand in solr's syntax. Now imagine taking input from a complex search and having to join or cat a bunch of strings with interpolations together to compose your query. It's a pain.

Comment: Yep, basically they're advertising the same difference as using an ORM vs. generating SQL by hand.

Comment: What Unixmonkey and Emily said. (I'm one of Sunspot's maintainers.)